# Origin of the "preposition+relative pronoun" construction as used to avoid sentence-terminal prepositions

Tags: prepositions, pied-piping

The rule against using prepositions to end sentences with is bogus—that much is clear—but what about the syntactic construction commonly used to avoid violating this rule, as parodied in the phrase popularly attributed to Winston Churchill, "the sort of nonsense up with which I shall not put"?

It takes the form of the preposition in question, followed by a relative pronoun (*that*, *which*, *whom*—never, in my experience, *who*, despite the declining usage of *whom*).  I'm seeing it less and less as the bogosity of the sentence-terminal preposition rule becomes better and better known, so what I'm wondering is when *this syntactic construction* came into use.  Something similar is used in formulae such as "To whom it may concern" and "In which..." followed by the description of whatever Winnie the Pooh does this chapter, but I'm specifically wondering about the form that is used to encapsulate in the middle of a sentence a preposition that would otherwise fall to the end.

Does this usage *only exist in the language to avoid using prepositions to end sentences with*, or does it predate that very prohibition?

EDIT: tchrist indicates by the addition of a tag that this sentence construction is an example of pied piping—this checks out.

Comment: In discussing Dryden's later practice of avoiding terminal prepositions, Fowler notes, "The natural inference from this would be: you cannot put a preposition (roughly speaking) later than its word in Latin, and therefore you must not do so in English." Fowler disagrees. The constructions you note are attempting to mirror Latin constructions in English. To do this, the English constructions must have come first (terminal prepositions).

Comment: Hot Licks: It's interesting that the rule is against _sentence_-terminal prepositions, but the construction itself doesn't always put the preposition at the end: "Using preposition to end a sentence with should never be done."

Comment: @Zan700: I believe that terminal prepositions show up in other Germanic languages too, so it's likely that the English version of them is very old.

Comment: It's not demonstrative pronouns (_this, that, these, those_); it's relative pronouns (_which, whom_).  When a relative pronoun is fronted, if it's the object of a preposition, the preposition may optionally be moved with it, preserving the prepositional phrase. And if that prepositional phrase modifies a noun phrase (as most do), that noun phrase may **also** be fronted along with its prepositional phrase. And if **that** noun phrase is also the object of a preposition, guess what else can happen?

Comment: @John Yes, relative. However the ones listed in the original post were all relative pronouns, and others could be added. Your explanation is known as pied piping, correct? Is this of Latin origin?

Comment: No, it's a term coined by Robin Lakoff for a syntactic process discussed by Ross in his dissertation. He presents recursive examples like _the reports, the height of the lettering on the covers of which is prescribed by law_